# best way to import data from SQL Server 7.0 to 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, import, sql-server-7

I have a table in a SQL Server 7.0 database with columns like:

```
Column_1      varchar(10)     null
Column_2      int             null
Column_3      varchar(15)     null
Column_4      float(53)       null
Column_5      float(53)       null
Column_6      text(16)        null
Column_7      text(16)        null
Column_8      varchar(25)     null
Column_9      datetime        null
```

and I need to move it to a table in SQL Server 2005.  What is the quickest and easiest way?  I would generally just `INSERT (cols...) SELECT cols.. FROM OtherDatabase.dbo.table` but I can't do that because it is SQL Server 7.0.

Comment: Import it from 2k5's Management Studio (right click db, task, import) and follow the wizard

Comment: @Alex K., I get the following error trying to connect to the SQL Server 7.0 server: `Cannot connect to YourServerName.  Additional information: This version of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio can only be used to connect to SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2005 servers (ConnectionDlg)`  I'm running SQl Server 2005 Enterprise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I haven't tried this (don't have a SQL 7.0 install handy :-)) you should be able to do something like below to setup a linked server and just get the data from a four part name query.

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;906954

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlsecurity/thread/7b24b699-f8b9-48e8-ba78-b037fd3b1d21/

Comment: I used this `sp_addlinkedserver @server=YourServerName` which worked with no errors.  However when I did this: `select * from YourServer.YourDatebase.dbo.YourTable` I got this error: `Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1, Line 0 Login failed for user 'MyUserName'.`

Comment: I created a new user with the same password on each server/database and when connected using this new user the select from the old database works.